# The scale bar shows a wrong scale

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

Adding a scale bar to my layout shows an incorrect scale (see image).

[image]

I am using EPSG:2097. What do I need to do to make the scale bar show the correct scale?

Comment: Which one is your projects CRS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working in QGIS' Layout Manager, you want to make sure that the scale bar is referred to a specific map which in turn needs to be in a projected CRS (from the `Map` drop-down menu):

[image]

That is because if CRS of the project is a Geographic one (i.e. Lat/Long), the scale bar is showing degrees, even if the label was forced to show 'm' for meters through the `Scalebar units` drop-down.

If you want a scale bar with lengths in actual meters/km/feet, change the project's CRS to a projected one (like UTM, for example).

From the menu `Project` -> `Properties` -> `CRS` tab

[image]

Lastly, make sure that in Layout Manager, the map referred to by the Scale bar object shows a projected CRS:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful! I've solved it now.